# Переходы между фрагментами в BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view

При переходах между фрагментами внизу отображается текущий фрагмент (подсвечивается иконка). Но при нажатии кнопки "назад" и хождению по стеку, bottomnavigation почему-то не работает и застывает на последнем нажатом вручную элементе. Как это исправить?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Fragment selectedFragment = new AFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    selectedFragment = new AFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_search:
                    selectedFragment = new BFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_add:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CreateMeetActivity.class));
                    setBorderActive(v_3);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    selectedFragment = new CFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_profile:
                    selectedFragment = new DFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    };

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Кнопка "назад" ничего не знает о вашем BottomNavigationView.

Можно при нажатии кнопки "назад" определить индекс текущего меню, и перейти на предыдущее.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ...
  //вынесем отдельно
  BottomNavigationView navigation;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
      ...
  }
  ...

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      int selected=0;
      //пробегаемся по всем меню
      for(int i=0; i<navigation.getMenu().size(); i++){
          //если элемент меню - текущий, то сохраняем и выходим из цикла
          if (navigation.getMenu().getItem(i).getItemId()==navigation.getSelectedItemId()) {
              selected=i;
              break;
          }
      }

      //если текущий элемент не первый
      if (selected>0) {
          //переходим на предыдущий элемент меню: selected-1 
          //setSelectedItemId имитирует нажатие на элементе меню
          navigation.setSelectedItemId(navigation.getMenu().getItem(selected-1).getItemId());
      } else {
          //если текущий элемент - самый первый, то вызываем метод предка
          super.onBackPressed();
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно переопределить нажатие кнопки назад.
У себя вот так делал:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int selectedItemId = bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId();
    if (R.id.navigation_main != selectedItemId) {
        loadFragment(mFirstFragment);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_main);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Фрагменты переключал вот так:

```
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() != menuItem.getItemId()) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_main:
                fragment = mFirstFragment;
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_taxi:
                fragment = new Pager_1();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_bus:
                fragment = new Pager_2();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_train:
                fragment = new TrainFrag();
                break;
        }
    }
    return loadFragment(fragment);
}
```

и в `onCreate`

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        loadFragment(mFirstFragment);
    }
```